# Write array of objects to mongo db in meteor using simple schema and appropriate security

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Looking for sample code that will take a variable that is an array of objects on the client side in Meteor, and write it to a mongo db collection, using a simple schema for validation, and appropriate security so that each user can only write to their own user collection entry. Looking for the syntax of both how the schema is set up, and also the steps of passing the data to the server, validating, checking write permission, and actually writing to the db.  A full example would be swell, and I hope will be useful to many.

Thanks

Comment: What's your attempt so far? For the part about declaring array of objects, it's quite clearely explained in the simple schema [documentation](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#schema-keys)

Comment: You've asked us to basically write a huge amount of functionality for you. This isn't what Stack Overflow is for, you need to post your attempt and ask for help with specific problems.